# Sort elements twice

Tags: android, kotlin

I made `Dialog` where user can sort the `List<Server>`. I gave him two options: 
1. sort by name
2. sort by players
This two options works fine separately, but when I try to combine them works only one option.
[SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZXJX.jpg)

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder? = activity?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it) }

        val view: View = activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_server_sort, null)
        builder?.setView(view)

        view.apply {
            rb_az.isChecked = mainActivityViewModel.az
            rb_za.isChecked = mainActivityViewModel.za
            rb_asc.isChecked = mainActivityViewModel.asc
            rb_desc.isChecked = mainActivityViewModel.desc


            btn_sort.setOnClickListener {
                if (rb_za.isChecked) {
                    mainActivityViewModel.za = true
                    mainActivityViewModel.az = false
                    listener.applySorts(mainActivityViewModel.filteredList.sortedByDescending { it.Name })
                } else if (rb_az.isChecked) {
                    mainActivityViewModel.az = true
                    mainActivityViewModel.za = false
                    listener.applySorts(mainActivityViewModel.filteredList.sortedByDescending { it.Name }.reversed())
                }

                if (rb_desc.isChecked) {
                    mainActivityViewModel.desc = true
                    mainActivityViewModel.asc = false
                    listener.applySorts(mainActivityViewModel.filteredList.sortedByDescending { it.NumPlayers })
                } else if (rb_asc.isChecked) {
                    mainActivityViewModel.asc = true
                    mainActivityViewModel.desc = false
                    listener.applySorts(mainActivityViewModel.filteredList.sortedByDescending { it.NumPlayers }.reversed())
                }
                dismiss()
            }

        }

        return builder!!.create()
}
```

EXAMPLE

```
list = (name=a players=4),(name=b players=1),(name=x players=c8),(name=n players=6)
sorted A-Z = a, b, n, x
sorted Z-A = x, n, b, a
sorted ASC = 1, 4, 6, 8
sorted DESC = 8, 6, 4, 1

sorted A-Z + ASC = (name=a players=4),(name=b players=1),(name=n players=6),(name=x players=c8)
```

Comment: For combining two sorts do you sort list using first sorting and after it you use second sort?

Comment: can you provide any example? I mean an example of your current result and your expected result?

Comment: @MdGolamRahmanTushar I added the example

Comment: Which one option? First one, that is sort by Name or sort by NumPlayers? i think you are not using updated sorted list from first sort into second sort conditions. Therefore, by looking at the code, I think the last two conditions of If returns the data.

Comment: @androidStud You right. Thanks!